# Sessions on two local Node.js servers

Tags: node.js, session, express, passport.js

I have two local Node.js servers:

1. http://localhost:3000
2. http://localhost:3001

I use express.js and passport.js for authentication. Authentication works correct, however if:

1. I login on server 1
2. I login on server 2

then session on server 1 disappears. How this could be prevented?

```
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
secret: '12345',
resave: true,
saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
function(username, password, done) {
  users.getActiveByUsername(username, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {console.log(err); return done(err); }
    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username' });
    }
    if (user.password != password) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password' });
    }
    return done(null, user);
  });
}
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
done(null, user);
});

app.post("/login", jsonParser, function(req, res, next) {
passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
  if (err) { return next(err); }
  if (!user) { res.status(400).send('Wrong username or password');return; }
  req.logIn(user, function(err) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    return res.json({'success':'Successful login'});
  });
})(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: please provide some code, specially where you are handling session.

Comment: I believe you have to store session cookie in some external storage like Redis and check validity of user's session inside each of Node.js servers.

Comment: @KayvanMazaheri added the code

Comment: @Artem validity of session is checked by passport.js, can you give more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using the same database for both of your applications.

You can't save sessions of different apps of the same host name on the same database **by default**. You have to make them distinguishable by using different names or prefixes.

If you are using `express-session` for handling your sessions, you can set different names via options:

```
app.use(session({
  secret: '12345',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  name: 'app1'          // use a different name for the second app
}));
```

Read the [official documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#name) of `express-session` for more info.

> **Note**
>   if you have multiple apps running on the same hostname (this is just the name, i.e. `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`; different schemes and ports do not name a different hostname), then you need to separate the session cookies from each other. The simplest method is to simply set different `names` per app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer